# Formatting Dates and Time for SMS using AMPScript in Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, datetime, content-builder, sms

Having a format issue on a SMS in Content Builder. Can someone point me to the correct code for this?

Also would love some advice to learn basic AMPScript coding. Books? Tutorials? Online classes?

Current:
This is a reminder that you have an appointment scheduled for: `%%AppointmentDateTime__c%%`

Displaying as:

> This is a reminder that you have an appointment scheduled for:
>   2019-09-05TO09:30:00

Should be showing as:

> This is a reminder that you have an appointment scheduled for: 9/05/19
>   at 9:30am.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [FormatDate()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dateTimeFormatting.htm) function:

```
%%=v(Concat(FormatDate(AppointmentDateTime__c,"M/dd/yy","", "en-US")," at ",FormatDate(AppointmentDateTime__c,"","HH:mmtt", "en-US")))=%%
```

Also Adam and Eliot have some great info on AMPScript that you can follow here: https://ampscript.guide/

Comment: Eliot also offers online and offline courses that address your learning goal: https://ampscript.academy/ The last one online was last week. You might contact him if there's anything coming up.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you!
I am going to devote more time in learning AMPscript. I am a newbie here.

Comment: Will check out the Guide and Academy